# Using Feeds Tamper to convert one list to another?

Tags: feeds

I am using a feeds importer to import a number of FIPS county codes for given locations and I was hoping to use the Feeds Tamper module to convert those county codes to county names, but have thus far been unsuccessful. Any ideas? I realize that there is a "Find replace" plugin for the Feeds Tamper, but seeing as this seems only to convert a single word or phrase at a time, I'd have to do this too many times for it to be worthwhile, though it does seem to reveal that the module is capable of doing the task I desire.

Thanks in advance,

David

Answer (score 0):

For like http://www.census.gov/2010census/xls/fips_codes_website.xls use Feeds or Migrate modules to fill-in a Content Type with the Fields in the Excel file. The are many tutorials online of importing data from a csv or excel sheet to Nodes.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear, sorry if that was the case. I already have all the FIPS codes within a content type, but I'd like a way to convert those codes to county names automatically (via Feeds Tamper or maybe, Taxonomy, I don't know)

Comment: sorry i dont understand your question. what fields or relationships do you want in your final Drupal structure of data for your website?

Comment: I apologize in advance for the long explanation. I have a "county" field in a content-type I've made. I've been searching for a file that relates the county to another field within that same content-type. While I couldn't find anything relating the county name, I found a file relating the county code. So I uploaded that to the county field in the content-type. However, I would like the county name instead of the county code, but do not wish to have to enter all the names in manually - though I could do that. Better?

Comment: If you have not found a file of `county names` -- you'll have to enter them by hand per Node. https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations or https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews should help you list all your nodes in 1 form to add county names and not have to edit each node individually.